# Why is viciously shaking a jar of water work in the thermodynamic sense?

Tags: thermodynamics

According to thermodynamics, internal energy can only be increased either by doing work on the system or heating the system. Work done on the system is defined by $$W=-P_\text{external}\times\Delta V$$

So when a jar of water is viciously shaken, the temperature of the water inside is increased. How is work done correlates over here?

Comment: This can be called "work" but it is different from pressure-volume work which requires change in volume.

Comment: There are many ways to do "work", i.e. transfer energy. If you put a resistor in a sealed, and allow electricity through, it will also get hot. In 1798, Benjamin Thomson showed that kinetic energy can be changed to thermal energy... but the details are boring.